# Displaying linear layout VS R.layout.activity main

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

So I'm new to android development and I'm having a bit a of a trouble.

I'm developing an an app which is going to have a similar background every time but imports a new image every time the user touches the screen.

HOWEVER my problem is that I'm having an issue right now in which I'm trying to load a new activity when a user click a button, 1) I followed one tutorial which had me use XML to add the button and program MAIN_activity to to switch to second_Activity using `setcontent(R.layout.main_Activity)` and works fine.

2) I also started another tutorial which had me use `setContent(layout1)` where layout one is in fact a LinearLayout which you addView(stuff) such as a button and program it to switch the second activity, but I'm failing terribly.

long story short, using this line `setcontent(R.layout.main_Activity)` overrides the `setContent(layout1)` info and I cant combine them. In addition I dont know how to make a button and click to switch activity except using the first method, I'm open to suggestions.

```
package self.name.firstandroidprogram;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    LinearLayout layout1;
    EditText number1Text;
    EditText number2Text;
    Button calcButton, switchButton;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
        number1Text = new EditText(this);
        number2Text = new EditText(this);
        calcButton = new Button(this);

switchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////BUTTON ACTIVITY SWTICH
        switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Class2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////






        answerText.setText("0");
        calcButton.setText("X");


        layout1.addView(number1Text);
        layout1.addView(number2Text);
        layout1.addView(calcButton);
        layout1.addView(answerText);
        layout1.addView(switchButton);




        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);// Works 

    //  setContentView(layout1) failes when i run




    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but try it

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
LinearLayout layout1;
EditText number1Text;
EditText number2Text;
Button calcButton, switchButton;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);

    // Do it before adding views in it.
    setContentView(layout1);

    number1Text = new EditText(this);
    number2Text = new EditText(this);
    calcButton = new Button(this);

switchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////BUTTON ACTIVITY SWTICH
    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Class2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////






    answerText.setText("0");
    calcButton.setText("X");


    layout1.addView(number1Text);
    layout1.addView(number2Text);
    layout1.addView(calcButton);
    layout1.addView(answerText);
    layout1.addView(switchButton);




//  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);// Works 






}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating view programatically you have to set each view LayourParameters using `view.setLayoutParams()`

Try this

```
        layout1 = new LinearLayout(this);

        EditText    number1Text = new EditText(this);
        EditText    number2Text = new EditText(this);
        Button  calcButton = new Button(this);

        calcButton.setText("X");
        //impt : width=MATCH_PARENT and height=MATCH_PARENT
        layout1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); //setting LL orientation

        layout1.addView(number1Text);
        layout1.addView(number2Text);
        layout1.addView(calcButton);


        setContentView(layout1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `LinearLayout` as your main layout. When user clicks the `switch` button, you need to set background of the `LinearLayout`

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<LinearLayout 
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/main"
 android:background="@drawable/default"
 >

     <!-- put your Button here switch button -->

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    switchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    LinearLayout lv1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              // we have reference of LinearLayout as lv1
              // we will change background of lv1 here when user clicks
              lv1.setBackgroundResource(<your_new_background_image_id>);
        }
    });
```

`<your_new_background_image_id>` can be fetched from `/res/drawable/` folder. You store 10-20 images of small size in `drawable` and rename them with similar name i.e. `image1`, `image2` etc

When setting them as background, you can code like :

```
int[] imageArray = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,...}

lv1.setBackgroundResource(imageArray[(i++)%10]);
```

Comment: i should replace the relativelayout with linearlayout in the xml right ?